# How do I align react-router NavLink in the bootstrap Navbar?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I want to use `NavLink` instead of `Nav.Link` in my `react-bootstrap` navbar so I can use the `activeClassName` prop. However it seems that all the links lose their alignment, there is no longer any horizontal margin between them and they are not centered vertically in the navbar:

[image]

code as follows:

```
function NavbarDefault() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Navbar variant="custom" expand="md">
                <Navbar.Brand as={NavLink} to="/">
                    <img 
                        className="navbar-logo-image" 
                        src={logo} alt="Brand Logo" />
                    <span className="navbar-logo-text">cool brand</span>
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle 
                    className="navbar-toggler-custom" 
                    aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav className="ml-auto">
                        <NavLink className="nav-link-custom" activeClassName="nav-link-custom-active" to="/features">Features</NavLink>
                        <NavLink className="nav-link-custom" activeClassName="nav-link-custom-active" to="/pricing">Pricing</NavLink>
                        <NavLink className="nav-link-custom" activeClassName="nav-link-custom-active" to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
                        <SecondaryButton 
                            className="navbar-login-button">
                                Try now
                        </SecondaryButton>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

and CSS:

```
.nav-link-custom {
    color: #41a2fb;
}
.nav-link-custom:hover {
    color: #0681EF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-link-custom-active {
    color: red;
}
```

Originally I tried to solve this problem by using something like `<Nav.Link as={NavLink} .......` this worked for the navigation and alignment however the `activeClassName` prop doesn't work that way, so I had to revert to `NavLink`. How can I center these nav links vertically in the navbar?